# Calculating sample size for quality samples with varying sizes/weights

Tags: sample-size

I am working on creating a QA program to measure the quality of translated documents. Each sentence in a document is evaluated and given a score based on the type of error in the sentence, with the type of errors being weighted. The document is scored based on the scores from each sentence. Thus a document with one sentence, if it has a severe error, the document receives a low score. Larger documents can thus have more errors and still receive higher scores.

Using a normal sample size calculation, I’m using z-score from my target confidence level (let’s say 85%), margin of error of 5%, and I am using standard deviation based on variance in QA scores across the previous sampled documents.

However, some documents are for example a few sentences with 25 words but some others are many sentences and 25000 words. If a given sample size has many small documents and one large document, the scores of the small documents may pull down the mean score of this sample population, even if the bulk of the translated sentences are found in the larger document, and when looking at the content as a whole, the quality is high.

What is a good way to determine sample size when my sample population varies in two ways (unit size and quality score) but I am just trying to sample/test for quality score? One way I have thought about is to make the sample unit sentences instead of documents, since that is where the score is made. But it is a bit harder to sample then because I cannot easily sample partial documents, though I suppose having more samples than n is not bad.

Additionally, even if the sample unit is sentences, sentences can also vary in size, though not as greatly.

The other thought I had was to change the scoring to weight the scores of each document by the total word count of the document. Something like quality score multiplied by total word count. This would then factor in both variance in the score and in the size of the document. But it feels like it dilutes the value of the QA score quite a lot.

Any other/better approaches?